# Python calls google Gmail API, and ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] is reported when running the verification program

Tags: python, ssl, gmail-api

The verification program code is as follows：

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']
def main():
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
    results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
    labels = results.get('labels', [])
    if not labels:
        print('No labels found.')
    else:
        print('Labels:')
        for label in labels:
            print(label['name'])
```

An error is reported when running to this line：

```
results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
```

The error message is：

```
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1076)
```

How can i solve this problem